# Why wont my nav display dropdown-links vertically?

Tags: html, css, nav

I have been sitting for 4 hours now trying to make my nav display dropdown-links vetically but it continues to show them horizontally instead. I can´t figure out why this is happening or how to fix it.

I would appreciate it very much if some kind soul could tell me what I am doing wrong. I have a sneaking suspecion this is caused due to my settings for the nav (it changes size at a certain width) but I am not sure...

I have ripped my nav from my website and thrown everything into codepen, but even after several attempts to figure out where the problem starts - nothing! It displays "link1" right below and then just adds "link2" and "link3" to the right of it, instead of under [image: like this]

Please help?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Pinchofginger/pen/BJJQgZ

If there are any oddities in the CSS it´s because I have a dropdown menu for mobile that display when you press an icon... it is not currently working either, but that a question for another time.

**My HTML**

```
 <header class="mainheader">
    <section id="baggrund">
      <div id="mainlogo">
        Sønderborg
        <p> og omegns</p> Kattelaug<br />
        <img class="vector" src="billeder/udklip.png" alt="Kattesilhuet"></div>


        <nav>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-checkbox" role="button" />
        <label for="menu-checkbox" id="menu-button">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        </label>
        <div id="nav_wrap">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Forside</a></li>
        <li><a href="adopt.html">Adopter en kat</a></li>
               <li><a href="till.html">Tilløber katte</a></li>
          <li> <a href="pas.html">Kattens pleje</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">
    Kontakt</a><div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul></div>
        </nav>
    </section>
  </header>
```

**MY CSS**

```
/* small nav */
@media screen and (max-width: 61em) {
  #menu li {
  width: 20%;
  }

  #menu li a {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  width:100%;
  color:red;}

  #menu ul {width:100%;}

  /*sidebar*/
  body#index .sidemenu .sidebar1 {padding: 0 0 0 0;}
  body#index #Mega {width: 96%; height:80px;}
  body#index .sidemenu .sidebar1 h3 {font-size: 0.9em;}

  }


/* stor nav*/
@media screen and (min-width: 61em) {
    #menu li {
    width: 20%;
  }

  #menu li a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width:100%;
    color: #505050;

      }} /*slut, stor*/


  #menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

  #menu li a {
text-transform: uppercase;
transition: all .5s ease;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
line-height: 55px;
display: inline-block;}

.sidemenu .pleje {font-size: 0.9em; display:inline-block }
.sidemenu .pleje h3 {color: orange;}

#mainlogo {
  display: block;
}

  .mainheader {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #bannerkat {  display: none;}
  #menu-button {  display: none;}

  #menu {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
  }

/* Navigations menuen (links osv) */
#nav_wrap {
  background: #f9f4ea;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 144px;
  bottom: 0;
/*  overflox:hidden;     */
  z-index: 9999;
  opacity: .9;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px beige;
  padding: 0;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}






/* højde for billed-sektion*/

.mainheader section {
  min-height: 204px;
}

#mainlogo {
  font-size: 37px;
  color: white;
  border: 7px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 123px;
  /* hvid boks*/
  line-height: 25px;
  top: 202px;
  margin-top: -180px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -300px;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #000;
}

/* og omegns */
#mainlogo p {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.vector {
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: -450px;
  margin-top: -36px;
}

.mainheader {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: take a look here it's always my go to no matter what vertical nav I want to start making https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 61em) { #menu {
    display: grid;
    float: left;  }` but i agree with @RobHern mobile menus with burger bar is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 42 in css: "menu li a" to Display: block instead of Display: inline-block:

```
#menu li a {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 transition: all .5s ease;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 55px;
 display: block;
}
```